# how to insert slash "\" use PHPExcel?

Tags: php, phpexcel

I want insert into slash in cell,for instance 
[image]

how can I do this use PHPExcel class?

Comment: I don't see any slash character there.

Comment: Have you read the documentation?

Comment: A1 and B2 is two slash

Comment: how do you do it in excel on your computer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$styleArray = array(
    'borders' => array(
        'diagonal' => array(
            'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THICK,
            'color' => array('argb' => 'FFFF0000'),
        ),
        'diagonaldirection' => PHPExcel_Style_Borders::DIAGONAL_DOWN,
    ),
);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:B2')->applyFromArray($styleArray);

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('A1:B2');
```